# Jenkinsfile JSON object is returning null

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline for automating rebasing forks with repos. I made a JSON that contains list of repos and it is like this

```
[
    {
      "name": "fork-sync-test",
      "fork": "git@<host>:<org>//fork-sync-test.git",
      "main": "git@<host>:<org>//fork-sync-test.git"
    }
]
```

and reading from Jenkinsfile like this

```
node {
    stage ('repo sync') {
        def repos = readJSON file: 'repo-list.json'
        echo "${repos[0].name}..."
        echo "${repos[0].fork}..."
    }
}
```

The output is

```
fork-sync-test...
null...
```

How can "name" key be read, while "fork" key can not. It doesn't make any sense. It should not need any libraries like JsonSlurper.

Also tried with and without escape character, but the result is the same.

Comment: What do you mean _"with and without escape character"_?

Comment: I mean the '/' char in the url string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. Jenkins couldn't sync SCM's master, so wasn't able to get json changes. For fixing this I added the code below to my Jenkinsfile

```
sh 'rm -rf <jenkins repo>'
sh 'git clone git@<host>:<org>/<jenkins repo>.git
```